# Run individual/selectable testcase(XCTestCase) from a testsuite in iOS from command line

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I have everything setup for my iOS UI Automation using XCUITest, i can run individual testsuites via

```
xcodebuild test -project <path> -scheme <name> -destination <specifier> -only-testing:TestBundle/TestSuiteName
```

I also used this command

```
xcodebuild test -workspace <path> -scheme <name> -destination <specifier> -only-testing:TestBundle/TestSuiteName/TestCase1 -only-testing:TestBundle/TestSuiteName/TestCase2
```

Using this i run these 2 tests but still they execute in alphabetical order not in the order in which i specified them in command.

Is there a way i can decide my order of testcase execution?
Is there a way i can run individual/selectable testcases via comamnd line?

I know we can use something like testInvocation to achieve the solution to my problem, but i am failing to understand how. I am using swift.

can someone help me out here.. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this. As you are running a single command xcTest framework handles this to run the testcases alphabetically in banckend.

If you want to run the test cases in pre defined order Then you have to use separate command and that is time consuming.

it is better to handle this inside testsuite and naming it accordingly